# Java Annotations - Is there any helper library to read/process annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I start to use Java annotations heavily.  One example is taking method with annotations and converting them into 'telnet'-based command-line command.  I do this by parsing annotations and hook into jopt option parser.

However, I do a lot of these manually.  For example, Method parameter annotation processing..

```
Method method = ... //;
Class[] parameters = method.getParamterTypes();
Annotation[][] annotations = method.getparamterAnnotations();

for( int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++ )
{
   // iterate through the annotation , see if each param has specific annotation ,etc.
}
```

It is very redundant and tedious.

Is there any opensource project that help processing Annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use this to look for a specific annotation:

```
for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        Object fieldValue = field.get(myObj);
        field.setAccessible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure which help do you need for annotations, but I'd suggesting that you take a look at my [Annox](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/User+guide) project. Here's [API](http://static.highsource.org/annox/annox/apidocs/index.html).

With Annox you can, for instance, read annotations into

- XAnnotation
- XAnnotationField
- XPackage
- XClass
- XConstructor
- XField
- XMethod
- XParameter

structures which might better suit your needs. You can read arbitrary annotations from XML, run visitors on them and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Any project would contain the exact same boilerplate code.  Why don't you make your own utility?

I'm sure you could use ASM:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cwt06075/
- http://asm.ow2.org/

Comment: I could write my own utility helper.  But I did not want to re-invent the wheel.  As for ASM, I use CGLIB(which uses ASM) to create dynamic proxy classes.

Comment: You could write your own utility as an open-source project, so that we could help and reuse it! :-)